# retrofit 2 deserialization error

Tags: android, jackson, retrofit

I'm currently trying to make a simple GET call to "https://hummingbirdv1.p.mashape.com" and I'm using the `JacksonConverterFactory`. The error I get is:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
```

I've been reading stack overflow and it seems its a problem with jackson and my POJO not being read correctly. Although If I use plain default Jackson core instead of the JacksonConverterFactory that comes with retrofit, it seems to parse just fine.

My POJO (I left out all the parcelable methods and getters and setters)

```
public class ListItem implements Parcelable {

private int id;
private int mal_id;
private String slug;
private String status;
private String url;
private String title;
private String alternate_title;
private int episode_count;
private int episode_length;
private String cover_image;
private String synopsis;
private String show_type;
private String started_airing;
private String finished_airing;
private float community_rating;
private String age_rating;
private ArrayList<Name> genres;

public ListItem() {
}

public ListItem(int id, int mal_id, String slug, String status, String url, String title, String alternate_title, int episode_count, int episode_length, String cover_image, String synopsis,
                String show_type, String started_airing, String finished_airing, float community_rating, String age_rating, ArrayList<Name> genres) {
    this.id = id;
    this.mal_id = mal_id;
    this.slug = slug;
    this.status = status;
    this.url = url;
    this.title = title;
    this.alternate_title = alternate_title;
    this.episode_count = episode_count;
    this.episode_length = episode_length;
    this.cover_image = cover_image;
    this.synopsis = synopsis;
    this.show_type = show_type;
    this.started_airing = started_airing;
    this.finished_airing = finished_airing;
    this.community_rating = community_rating;
    this.age_rating = age_rating;
    this.genres = genres;
}
```

An example response that I want to parse is:

```
{


"id": 1,
  "mal_id": 1,
  "slug": "cowboy-bebop",
  "status": "Finished Airing",
  "url": "https://hummingbird.me/anime/cowboy-bebop",
  "title": "Cowboy Bebop",
  "alternate_title": "",
  "episode_count": 26,
  "episode_length": 24,
  "cover_image": "https://static.hummingbird.me/anime/poster_images/000/000/001/large/hNSma.jpg?1431697256",
  "synopsis": "Enter a world in the distant future, where Bounty Hunters roam the solar system. Spike and Jet, bounty hunting partners, set out on journeys in an ever struggling effort to win bounty rewards to survive.\r\nWhile traveling, they meet up with other very interesting people. Could Faye, the beautiful and ridiculously poor gambler, Edward, the computer genius, and Ein, the engineered dog be a good addition to the group?",
  "show_type": "TV",
  "started_airing": "1998-04-03",
  "finished_airing": "1999-04-24",
  "community_rating": 4.48547657328022,
  "age_rating": "R17+",
  "genres": [
    {
      "name": "Action"
    },
    {
      "name": "Adventure"
    },
    {
      "name": "Comedy"
    },
    {
      "name": "Drama"
    },
    {
      "name": "Sci-Fi"
    },
    {
      "name": "Space"
    }
  ]
}
```

The service that uses Retrofit:

```
AnimeRequestService {
public static String MASHAPE_BASE_URL = "https://hummingbirdv1.p.mashape.com";
private static String MASHAPE_DEBUG_KEY = "()*&#()$*)#(&*$)@(#&*$";
private final MashapeService mashapeService;
private final String TAG = AnimeRequestService.class.getCanonicalName();


public AnimeRequestService() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.networkInterceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public com.squareup.okhttp.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("X-Mashape-Key", MASHAPE_DEBUG_KEY).addHeader("accept", "application/json").build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(MASHAPE_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();

    mashapeService = retrofit.create(MashapeService.class);

}


public interface MashapeService {
    @GET("/anime/{id}")
    Call<List<ListItem>> fetchList(@Path("id") int id);
}

public void callService(int id) {
        Call<List<ListItem>> call = mashapeService.fetchList(id);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<ListItem>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<List<ListItem>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                for (ListItem listItem : response.body()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, listItem.getTitle());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Log.i(TAG,t.toString());
            }
        });

}
```

Can anyone see why the parsing would fail from `JacksonConverterFactory` but not Jackson core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to deserialize an array, but you are only getting an single json object.  Try updating your call to look for an object instead of a list.

```
public interface MashapeService {
    @GET("/anime/{id}")
    Call<ListItem> fetchList(@Path("id") int id);
}

public void callService(int id) {
        Call<ListItem> call = mashapeService.fetchList(id);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ListItem>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<ListItem> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                for (ListItem listItem : response.body()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, listItem.getTitle());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Log.i(TAG,t.toString());
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That was the problem.